# How automatically compile jsx or tsx to js into visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, reactjs, jsx, tsx

How automatically compile react jsx or tsx to js into visual studio code?
Is a task runner needed? or just a configuration into jsconfig.json?

What I already tried:

I already tried to create a jsconfig.json with jsx parameter without success.
I configured a TS compiler, however it compiles only TS to JS, not JSX to JS.

I'm wondering if there any configuration that makes this conversion without need to configura a run task. , for instance "compile on save" like the Full Visual Studio.

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far. ;)

Comment: nothing to much, Just studying .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+s",          
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build" 
    }
]
```

to keybindings.json

and create file tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "webpack",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```